# Extracting Delegates in generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

After some benchmarks I noticed most of my methods I created which use reflection are very, very slow, especially when used in iterations. I found a post from [C# Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/boosting-up-the-reflection-performance-in-c-sharp/), which shows how to create delegates for the reflection methods, because the validation and security operations are only done once when creating the delegate instead of each loop.

The C# Corner post show a code example very similar to this:

```
public class Item
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
}


List<Item> list = Enumerable.Repeat(new Item(), 10000000).ToList();

int i = 0;
foreach (var element in list)
{
  i = element.Value;
  element.Value = 3; 
}
```

and then explains that using reflection instead has the drawback of drastically affecting performance:

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(Item).GetProperty("Value");

foreach (var element in list)
{
  i = (int)propInfo.GetValue(element);
  propInfo.SetValue(element, 3);
}
```

performance however can be improved by creating delegates:

```
Action<Item, int> setter = (Action<Item, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Action<Item, int>), null,
    typeof(Item).GetProperty("Value").GetSetMethod());

Func<Item, int> getter = (Func<Item, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<Item, int>), null,
    typeof(Item).GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod());

foreach (var element in list)
{
  i = (int)getter(element);
  setter(element, 3);
}
```

Now some of my methods have generic type parameters and I haven't found out how to create delegates with generic parameters yet to get a similar performance boost.
**Example: Let's say I have following extension method and I want to move the reflection calls to delegates, how would I do this**?

```
public static void SetValues<T>(this List<T> list)
{
  var propInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties().AsSpan();

  for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) 
  {
    var element = list[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < propInfos.Length; j++)
    {

      var propInfo = propInfos[j];
      if (propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int) && (int)propInfo.GetValue(element) == default)
        propInfo.SetValue(element, i);
    }
  }
}
```

I've found various solutions, that use an `ILGenerator` to do this, as found in this [MSDN Blog Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-a-generic-method-with-reflection-emit), but that has honestly been a little to abstract for my taste. I'd like to stay with C#, if possible.

### Edit:

A lot of people asked why I use reflection at all, so I want to provide an example where I actually use it: I have frontend that is able to connect to multiple databases where tables have different column names. Like illustrated here:

```
//Preperation
var list = new List<Item>();
var database = (DatabaseSource)new Random().Next(0, 3);

DataTable source = new DataTable();

switch (database)
{
  case DatabaseSource.db1:
    source.Columns.Add("Val", typeof(int));
    break;
    case DatabaseSource.db2:
    source.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
    break;
    case DatabaseSource.db3:
    source.Columns.Add("IntValue", typeof(int));
    break;
}

source.Rows.Add(5);
source.Rows.Add(2);
```

Now if i were to handle this manualle, I'd do something like this:

```
switch (database)
{
  case DatabaseSource.db1:
    foreach(DataRow row in source.Rows)
    {
      list.Add(new Item 
      {
        Value = Convert.ToInt32(row["Val"]) 
        //More Properties
     });
    }
    break;
  case DatabaseSource.db2:
    foreach (DataRow row in source.Rows)
    {
      list.Add(new Item
      {
        Value = Convert.ToInt32(row["Value"])
        //More Properties
      });
    }
    break;
  case DatabaseSource.db3:
    foreach (DataRow row in source.Rows)
    {
      list.Add(new Item
      {
        Value = Convert.ToInt32(row["IntValue"])
        //More Properties
      });
    }
    break;
}
```

which takes a lot of place for models with more than 1 property. My idea was to add an Attribute to my models like this:

```
  public class ConvertAttribute : Attribute
  {
    public string[] Columns { get; private set; }
    public ConvertAttribute(string[] columns)
    {
      Columns = columns;
    }

  }

  public class Item
  {
    [Convert(new[] { "Val", "Value", "IntValue" })]
    public int Value { get; set; }
  }
```

Now I can use reflection to automate this process:

```
 public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(this DataTable table)
{
  var list = new List<T>();
  var propInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
  var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
  var columnNames = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();
  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
  {
    foreach (var propInfo in propInfos)
    {
      var attributes = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true);
      foreach (var attribute in attributes)
      {
        if (attribute is ConvertAttribute convertAttribute)
        {
          foreach (var columnName in convertAttribute.Columns)
          {
            if (columnNames.Contains(columnName))
            {
              var value = row[columnName];
              if (value.GetType() == propInfo.PropertyType)//Use default Converter in Case "value" is a ordinary value Type
                propInfo.SetValue(obj, value);
              else
              {
                if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                  propInfo.SetValue(obj, Enum.ToObject(propInfo.PropertyType, int.Parse(value.ToString())));

                else
                  propInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, propInfo.PropertyType));
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    list.Add(obj);
  }
  return list;
}
```

which means no matter which model, no matter what properties, I can call this instead:

```
var l = source.ConvertToList<Item>();
```

reducing 32 or more lines in my ViewModels to 1 reduces the clutter quite a lot, but now I want to improve performance. Maybe I am on a wrong way here at all?

Comment: Just for the record and to get it off the table: Do you _actually need_ reflection to begin with? What are you doing with this?

Comment: Why are you using reflection in the first place? You `SetValues` method does not make much sense to me, why would I ever want to use such a method? If the idea is to set some id to the index you should probably create a extension method that use a delegate to specify what property to set, something like `myList.ForEach((value, index) => value.Id = index);`

Comment: Can't you simply replace `Item` by `T` when creating the setter and the getter? Where is the problem?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Question has become quite long now, but I included an example where I currently use reflection. I could do without it, but can reduce a few 100 lines of code by using it. If my approach is misguided, feel free to tell me.

Comment: _" I have frontend that is able to connect to multiple databases where tables have different column names."_ - Is that multiple databases as in "multiple _known_ databases with known schemas" or as in "_any_ database with _any_ schema"?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods multiple known databases with known schemas. User should be able to log out and connect to a different database without having to close and restart the app. I also can't change the backend, so the datatable can only be converted in the frontend.

Comment: Note that O/R-mappers are solving the problem that you are trying to solve. E.g.: [Dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/#what-does-dapper-do) is a very simple to use and very fast. Replace your `ConvertToList<T>` by just one line of code.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes I creplace `Item` by `T`, but it runs as fast as without delegates. Seems the generic type requires the same security operations as reflection, even if reflection is extracted as a delegate. 

I will see if I can use Dapper. Nuget packages are limited for the company I am working for, so I first have to create a ticket and wait for the package to hopefully be approved :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static generic helper class which caches the properties.

```cs
public static void SetValues<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) 
    {
        var element = list[i];
        foreach (var prop in GenericHelper<T>.Properties)
        {
            if (prop.getter(element) == default)
                prop.setter(element, i);
        }
    }
}

static class GenericHelper<T>
{
    public static List<(Func<T, int> getter, Action<T, int> setter)> Properties = new();

    static GenericHelper()
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(int) || !prop.CanRead || !prop.CanWrite || prop.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
                continue;
            var getter = prop.GetMethod.CreateDelegate<Func<T, int>>();
            var setter = prop.SetMethod.CreateDelegate<Action<T, int>>();
            Properties.Add((getter, setter));
        }
    }
}
```

If the properties themselves can be of different types then you need a separate generic class (which has a non-generic base class) which can do what you need to do, and you cache objects of those instead.

Comment: Your code works, but after testing it with BechmarkDotNet, it doesn't seem to properly emit the reflection. While using delegates as shown in the example from C# Corner reduces the time from 2,293,823.44 ns to 333,634.30 ns (compared to 85,897.89 ns w/o reflection), your code is as fast as my example code with 1,928,127.76 ns  to 1,922,027.06 ns (for a List with 100k entries)

Comment: What version of .Net are you running? I tested countless times and actually found a bug, that caused inaccuracies, but still couldn't achieve the same increase in performance as you (although I reduce memory usage from 0.7MB to 2B, which will come handy with GC). Just to be sure, I tested with .Net 5,6 and 7 and noticed in .Net 5 and 6 the unoptimized method takes 11,306.587 ns compared to yours with 2,320.731 ns while in net 7 the unoptimized method is down to 3,433.278 ns (100k items). I don't know how, since memory usage stays the same, but this seems to be opmtized in .Net 7.

Comment: I'm using .NET7. Can you construct a https://dotnetfiddle.net with your code? I can only guess you are not using my code properly

Comment: Here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iyPQuX Also Included the Benchmarks I ran in VS22 with this exact same code. Haven't run it in .Net Fiddle due to not knowing how to resolve the missing CLI there, but it's the exact same code.

Comment: Looking at your results, you can see `SetValuesGeneric` is far slower than `SetValuesHelperClass` eg for 100k items 11,341.582 us against 2,441.303 us for .NET 6. I do note that .NET 7 seems to be much less of a difference, presumably there has been a significant performance improvement in reflection there, still faster though. My own results are more clearcut: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xOqtYj you can clearly see my code is faster.

Comment: I didn't doubt your code is faster after fixing my bug, just was curious as to why my approach appeared to be slower by a magnitude compared to yours, when having the same .Net version. (Seems like too large of a difference to be done between patches - I used 7.0.2 btw), so I was just worried I messed up somewhere.

Comment: Because I'm caching the delegates to the functions. Doing the reflection on every run is very slow, so caching delegates to each setter speeds it up significantly, as the reflection is only done once.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that unclear. I meant I was confused as to why your code is about 10 times faster in your tests as compared to 50% increased speed when run by me, but it seems like Microsoft just improved Reflection in general.